# Where to store a private data for ionic2 application

Tags: ionic2

I'm building ionic2 application with angular2 , let's say I have a private data which the angular2 scripts need to use. my question is:

- Does the scripts files under www folder (before building to android /
  ios) can be opened and read by someone holding the APK / IPA after
  building ?

  If the scripts can be accessed , where should one put a data that one
  don't want it to be accessed ?

Comment: What kind of data do you want to store?

Comment: I want to store a string, I think it is not relevant what kind of data, the issue is weather the user can see the bundle.js files in some way ,or is it safe build into the APK.

Comment: Users can extract resources as far as I know. You better to get your secret string from server over HTTPS but even then it can be retrieved by someone using debug.

Comment: So all the js files are stored in resources that can be extracted from the APK ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=extracting+files+from+apk, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15183/can-i-extract-application-data-from-an-ios-device